# Woocommerce [woocommerce_cart] shortcode not working

Tags: woocommerce, shortcode

So I'm working on this website and I'm using the woocommerce plugin.
The plugin is working fine and I can add things to my cart the only problem is that I can't view my cart. The image I've added shows my "Cart" page and you can see it just simply shows the shortcode.

http://gyazo.com/f0710eeb2fd63643bb74607988559e02

I have no idea why it isn't working :(

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found out what was wrong, I had to add this little bit of code in the page.php file:

```
<?php
echo apply_filters('the_content',$wp_query->post->post_content);
?>
```

Hope it will help anyone else too :)

Comment: You can also just use the normal WordPress loop if you planned to use anything from `the_post()`.

For anyone unsure of "why" this answer works, it just means that your template file had no call to `the_content()` and so the shortcode in your page/post wasn't being seen or run by WordPress. @branco holtslag's answer is one method of retrieving `the_content()`.

Comment: Thanks. got it working again. I'm still wondering why did it happen.  Where did you get this information? Is it in the documentation?

Comment: Same problem, doesn't work for me.  Just echo's "[woocommerce_cart]" again so it shows twice on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across this issue this week. I found that deleting the cart page and regenerating it with Woocommerce fixed it.

Go to Woocommerce > Settings > Utilities > "Create default WooCommerce pages"